# Guarantees on the Object lifetime of inline static Meyers singleton, with explicit placement in a section?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I have inherited some code that compiles fine under g++ 9 and 10, but gives a runtime error for both compilers when optimization is turned on (that is, compiling -O0 works, but compiling -Og gives a runtime error from the MMU.)

The problem is that there is a Meyers singleton defined in an inline static method of a class, and that object seems to be optimized away.  There is a complication that the static object in the method is declared with a section attribute (this is the g++ language extension for placing options in specific sections in the object file.)

Here is a summary of the situation.

File c.hpp

```
namespace my_prod {

   class C {
   // C has a default c'tor
   public:
   static C& instance() {
      static C c __attribute__((section("MY_C_SECTION")));
      return c;
   }

   void f();
   };
}
```

File c.cpp

```
#include "c.hpp"

using namespace my_prod;

void C::f() {
   // implementation of f, doesn't use instance()
}
```

File p.hpp

```
namespace my_prod {

   class P {
   public:
   static void g();
   };
}
```

Then file p.cpp

```
#include "p.hpp"
#include "c.hpp"

using namespace my_prod;

void P::g() {
    C::instance().f();
}
```

The linker script includes:

```
MEMORY
{
   BIG_CHUNK (rw) : ORIGIN = <address>, LENGTH = <enormous>
}

SECTIONS
{
   .my_space (NOLOAD) :
   {
      . = ALIGN(32);
      *(MY_C_SECTION)
   } > BIG_CHUNK
}
```

For both optimization levels, `objdump -C -r -t p.o` gives

```
00000000  w    O MY_C_SECTION    00002220 my_prod::C::instance::c
```

(ie, so not local, not global, but it is weak.)

But objdump on the elf file shows that symbol in BIG_CHUNK when optimization is -O0, but missing when it is -Og.

It may be relevant that the project defines the following switches::

```
-ffunction-sections
-fdata-sections
-Wl,--gc-sections
```

although these switches are applied consistently for all builds.

The solution was to move the definition of the `my_prod::C::instance()` method into c.cpp.  The symbol is then locally defined and not weak anymore, and appears in the final elf irrespective of the optimization level.

My question is, what are the rules of C++ that explain this behavior?

Comment: I think you're firmly in "implementation-specific" land here.

Comment: The C++ standard kind of takes a back seat when you use compiler extensions. At that point compiler specifications take over. A compiler is allowed to provide optional modes which do not conform to or override standard requirements.

Comment: `--gc-sections` is not a safe option. It can remove symbols that may be required, in particular in static initialization. I recommend first trying without that flag.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately the program doesn't fit without it.  
Thanks also to FrançoisAndrieux and molbdnilo for your comments.
I'm a bit confused by the evidence, truth be told. With -Og, the call to C::instance is optimized away. Stepping through instructions goes from P::g to C::f; it looks like it's using register 0 for the address of the object 'c', and it's 0.

Comment: Although my example doesn't show it, there are a lot of things included in the `.my_space` output section in the linker script.  Objdump of the elf shows many things in the `.my_space`, showing at least that the section wasn't garbage collected.  Piping the output through `| grep '.my_space' | wc -l` gives 54.

Comment: Is the description actually meant to reproduce the issue? I suspect it's incomplete in some aspects. Are there more symbols defined in `MY_C_SECTION`?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Yes, there are more symbols in `MY_C_SECTION`.
The description is a summary of the issue.  Note that I've found a work-around --- move the `instance` method into the cpp file.  I was looking for help to understand how a change to optimization could change the effect of the program; in particular, if it is a sign that the program is ill-formed.  The comments from molbdnilo and Francois suggest I might never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC uses [COMDAT section groups](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.sheader.html#section_groups) when available to implement [vague linkage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html). Despite being explicitly named as `MY_C_SECTION`, the compiler still emits a COMDAT group with `_ZZN7my_prod1C8instanceEvE1c` as the key symbol:

```
    .section    MY_C_SECTION,"awG",@progbits,_ZZN7my_prod1C8instanceEvE1c,comdat
```

I expect that your other uses of `MY_C_SECTION` are *not* part of a COMDAT group with the same signature symbol. This creates an ambiguous situation for section garbage collection by the link editor.

Without optimization, the compiler emits a reference to the `_ZZN7my_prod1C8instanceEvE1c` signature symbol, and it happens that in this particular implementation of linker garbage collection, this is enough to retain the `MY_C_SECTION` section in the object file and the `_ZZN7my_prod1C8instanceEvE1c` symbol definition. With optimization, that reference is gone, and due to the ambiguity of the situation, the link editor discards the definition.

Without an inline definition of `my_prod::C::instance()`, there is no vague linkage and COMDAT group involved, so the ambiguity does not arise, and the linker script works as expected.

To address this while preserving the inline definition, it may be sufficient to use a unique section name instead of `MY_C_SECTION` and reference that in the linker script.